# Driving compact UV lamp with DC

Tags: lamp, electronic-ballast

I'm 'testing the water' if you will on driving a [Panasonic TUV PL-S 5W](https://www.prouvlamps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/TUVPL-S5W2P.pdf) UV lamp with a low-voltage (12 ~ 24 V) DC supply.  The lamp is rated at 34 V, 0.18 A.

Since I have a DC source, magnetic ballasts are out.  I have read some app notes from [ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00003901.pdf) and [Infineon](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/tp-120621-2.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153573fc6573ea6) on electronic ballast design, yet these sources are concerned with mains-connected fluorescent lamps (i.e. the artificial sun above your cubicle).

The closest products I could find are the [UC3872](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3872.pdf) and [UCC2973](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2973.pdf) which seem geared towards automotive and laptop computer applications.

[image: UC3872]

Since the lamp is only rated for 34 V I would use a different transformer (1:3 for 12 V, etc.).  Other than that I feel a bit clueless.  Am I heading in the right direction, or are there simpler slash better paths to take?

**EDIT:** a dimmable feature is not needed.

Comment: Are you trying to produce 34 volts DC for the lamp?

Comment: @Andyaka I assume the 34 V is high-frequency (~10 kHz) AC, but my knowledge of driving lamps goes back only a few hours ago.

Comment: The lamp is rated with 34 V and 0.18 A, the resulting power is 6.12 W. But the lamp is rated to 5 W only. You may need a power control limiting lamp power.

Comment: @calcium3000 I'm noooo expert on these lamps but I'm hoping to learn something nonetheless. Roll-on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ignition voltage is unknown yet, may be 68V or 2x conduction voltage , so 1:6 transformer with current sensing regulating seems feasible.  Unless centre tap doubles this ratio with Vpp ratio

It seems your 2 pin tube is designed for magnetic ballasts with internal switch while 4 pin versions are for electronic ballasts.

Here is a magnetic entire solution for <20$. https://m.ebay.ca/itm/UV-disinfection-lamp-electronic-ballast-PL-S-5W-9W-11W-universal-lamp-holder/182962632880?hash=item2a996c38b0%3Ag%3A6LsAAOSw0RdaMgVr&_mwBanner=1&_nkw=pl-s+ballast&rt=nc

But it’s not dimmable.

Comment: Good catch -- just saw "4-Pin PL-S lamps are designed for use on electronic drivers" on the Panasonic product page.  Switching to a 4-pin version shouldn't be a problem.  However, your magnetic solution doesn't solve the DC input problem; I would need an additional DC-AC inverter on the front end, which is a no-go.

Comment: It doesn’t say what the ballast input is.  Go with electronic ballast for lowest start current longer life and higher efficacy at high frequency.